# A "dynamic bitfield" in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

In this question, assume all integers are unsigned for simplicity.

Suppose I would like to write 2 functions, pack and unpack, which let you pack integers of smaller width into, say, a 64-bit integer.  However, the location and width of the integers is given at runtime, so I can't use C bitfields.

Quickest is to explain with an example.  For simplicity, I'll illustrate with 8-bit integers:

```
             * *
bit #    8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
myint    0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1
```

Suppose I want to "unpack" at location 5, an integer of width 2.  These are the two bits marked with an asterisk.  The result of that operation should be 0b01.  Similarly, If I unpack at location 2, of width 6, I would get 0b100011.

I can write the unpack function easily with a bitshift-left followed by a bitshift right.

But I can't think of a clear way to write an equivalent "pack" function, which will do the opposite.

Say given an integer 0b11, packing it into myint (from above) at location 5 and width 2 would yield

```
             * *
bit #    8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
myint    0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1
```

Best I came up with involves a lot of concatinating bit-strings with OR, << and >>.  Before I implement and test it, maybe somebody sees a clever quick solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Off the top of my head, untested.

```
int pack(int oldPackedInteger, int bitOffset, int bitCount, int value) {
    int mask = (1 << bitCount) -1;
    mask <<= bitOffset;
    oldPackedInteger &= ~mask;
    oldPackedInteger |= value << bitOffset;
    return oldPackedInteger;
}
```

In your example:

```
int value = 0x63;
value = pack(value, 4, 2, 0x3);
```

To write the value "3" at an offset of 4 (with two bits available) when 0x63 is the current value.

Comment: Yep. And similarly for the unpack method: The OP doesn't need to use "a bitshift-left followed by a bitshift right" to unpack; a right-shift followed by an `&` would do the trick.

Comment: @Luke: I don't quite get the example though. How does the unpack result in 0x0b01 and 0xb100011?

Comment: @EboMike, bit 5 is 0, bit 6 is 1.

Comment: @EboMike, tested it and your solution works -- thanks! Nice trick with (1 << bitCount) - 1.

Comment: @EboMike: And to answer comment regarding the premise, for posterity's sake.  A normal bitfield is what I was looking for.  I.e. "packing" an integer into one place shouldn't change the other stuff within the integer.

Comment: @Max: Glad to help! Bit magic is awesome, the possibilities are endless.

Comment: will fails if bitcount is 32

Comment: Use `unsigned` integers for this kind of things always, so that you prevent UB from overflow.  Also, I would recommend fixed width ones.